# The console.trace() function log only the current function instead of the whole stacktrace

Tags: javascript

I am having trouble debugging my code, and the console.trace function seems to behave weirdly.

I have a code such as:

```
func1() {  
   console.trace("hey");  
}  
   
func2() {  
   func1();  
}

func2();
```

The resulting log looks like this:

```
"hey"  
func1 @ script.js:2
```

This is not really helpful as you can see. What could explain this kind of behaviour ?

Comment: Apart from missing the `function` keyword twice, i get full stack trace in both chrome and FF. Where are you running this?

Comment: This is an example code, the actual functions are in a class, hence no function keyword. This is running in a sandboxed electron renderer script (no "require")

Comment: @dododingo Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure why `console.trace()` behaves like this, I did find a workaround as I needed proper stack traces. Simply replacing all `console.trace(...)` calls with `console.log(..., (new Error()).stack)` resulted in stack traces working, sometimes with far more detail.

Answer (score 0):

In your example,the behavior of **console.trace([message][, ...args])** is exactly what is expected

### Explanation

```
const func1 = () => {
  console.trace("hey");
}

const func2 = () => {
  func1();
}

func2();
```

## Here

1. func2 is called
2. func2 calls func1
3. func1 program halts and emit a stack trace.

```
  Trace: hey 
     at func1 (/script.js:2:11)
     at func2 (/script.js:6:3)
```

- You can see from the above error, func1 was called by func2.
- From this we understand which functions called each other.
- We can also see the line number and file that the function exists on
- The topmost line is the error message we passed.
- The stack trace helps us to know the steps that lead up to our error.
- Now we know where our stack trace generated which is in the func1.
- That's why func1 is showing at the top. This will make our whole debugging process easier.

Please refer this:

1. https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#consoletracemessage-args
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error/Stack

Comment: according to this documentation, I should see a  `stack trace to the current position in the code`, shouldn't it contain the parent function `func2` ?

Comment: @dododingo, I have edited to answer your question. Please check